# Output an element under not empty namespace URI

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

http://www.google.com/support/news_pub/bin/answer.py?answer=93992

Is there an easy way to create a sitemap to support Google News Sitemap . I've been trying to find a way of including `<news:news>` into the XSLT and I keep getting errors.

Comment: Have you declared the corresponding namespace for `news` prefix?

Comment: see my answer for an example.

Comment: What is "Google News Sitemap"? Where is the source XML document? What is the wanted result? This doesn't seem to be an XSLT question at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <urlset>
            <url>
                <loc>http://www.example.org/business/article55.html</loc>
                <news:news>
                    <news:publication>
                        <news:name>The Example Times</news:name>
                        <news:language>en</news:language>
                    </news:publication>
                    <news:access>Subscription</news:access>
                    <news:genres>PressRelease, Blog</news:genres>
                    <news:publication_date>2008-12-23</news:publication_date>
                    <news:title>Companies A, B in Merger Talks</news:title>
                    <news:keywords>business, merger, acquisition, A,</news:keywords>
                    <news:stock_tickers>NASDAQ:A, NASDAQ:B</news:stock_tickers>
                </news:news>
            </url>
        </urlset>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to any XML input (not used) result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
    xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.org/business/article55.html</loc>
        <news:news>
            <news:publication>
                <news:name>The Example Times</news:name>
                <news:language>en</news:language>
            </news:publication>
            <news:access>Subscription</news:access>
            <news:genres>PressRelease, Blog</news:genres>
            <news:publication_date>2008-12-23</news:publication_date>
            <news:title>Companies A, B in Merger Talks</news:title>
            <news:keywords>business, merger, acquisition, A, B</news:keywords>
            <news:stock_tickers>NASDAQ:A, NASDAQ:B</news:stock_tickers>
        </news:news>
    </url>
</urlset>
```